# Using Table1_mc to get descriptive statistics with total and by exposure

Tags: stata

I am a new Stata user trying to create a Table 1 using table1_mc. The code below gives me results by study treatment arm (PBL_treat). I have been trying to add a total option to get a column with all study participants as well, but keep getting the error "option total incorrectly specified." Does anyone know how to correctly specify the total option? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: I'd try Statalist. I am aware of `table_mc` but have never used it and evidently the same applies to other people who answer Stata questions here.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line, try adding: `total(before)` or `total(after)`

e.g. `nospace percent oncecol missing total(before)`

According to the help document: `help table1_mc`

"total(before|after) - include a total column before/after presenting by group"